# Dax measure to look up the latest value in a column based on a date slicer

Tags: date, powerbi, dax, price, inventory-management

I have a table that has three columns, date (going back to 2017), product (same group of stock items ordered at different times) and price (price varies each time ordered).

I calculate the total stock issued each month and need a measure that looks up the last price, not the max price, based on a date selected by a slicer. The final aim being to have a report that I can quickly analyse year of stock data.

The measure I have MAXX('stockin','stockin'[unitprice]) sort of works but only gives the maximum price paid or if the item wasn't ordered that month(as selected on the slicer), no value (stock can be issued but not ordered for the month).

I tried to make some of the similar solutions work but can't seem to make them work for me.

Can anyone offer any solutions or ideas for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your table is in the right order, then you can use either `FIRSTNONBLANK` or `LASTNONBLANK`.

```
LASTNONBLANK('stockin'[unitprice], 1)
```

And if your are looking for the last value even before the slicer range then:

```
YourMeasure = 
  var maxDateSelected = LASTDATE('YourDateTable'[Date])
  var maxDateAvaialble = CALCULATE(
    LASTDATE('stockin'[date]),
    FILTER(ALL('stockin'), NOT ISBLANK('stockin'[unitprice]) && 'stockin'[date] <= maxDateSelected )
  )

  RETURN CALCULATE(
      LASTNONBLANK('stockin'[unitprice], 1),
      FILTER( ALL('stockin'[date]), 'stockin'[date] = maxDateAvaialble )
    )
```

Comment: Thanks Sam, but that doesn't seem to work for me. I tried slicing a month that had two different prices and the earliest price was found and if I select a month that didn't have any stock delivered, or a future month, nothing shows up, I'd like to reference all history prior to selected date. Could there be something wrong with my date table or how the slicer is configured (tiles)?

Comment: Updated the second part to the answer above. Give that a go.

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error, I think with the maxSelectedAvailable line the var doesn't appear as selectable in intellisense, and can't seem to correct it

Comment: I had to guess what your date column is called in `stockin` table. Update it as needed.

Comment: And if you don't have a Date column in `stockin` and instead it is a key, then replace `LASTDATE('stockin'[date])` with `MAX('stockin'[date])`

Comment: Thanks, I'd left out a bracket, it works and finds the latest value value. Still have an issue with the slicer but thats a different question.